# Correct way to Convert 16bit PCM Wave data to float

Tags: java, android, pcm, audio-processing

I have a wave file in 16bit PCM form. I've got the raw data in a `byte[]` and a method for extracting samples, and I need them in float format, i.e. a `float[]` to do a Fourier Transform. Here's my code, does this look right? I'm working on Android so `javax.sound.sampled` etc. is not available.

```
private static short getSample(byte[] buffer, int position) {
  return (short) (((buffer[position + 1] & 0xff) << 8) | (buffer[position] & 0xff));
}

...

float[] samples = new float[samplesLength];
  for (int i = 0;i<input.length/2;i+=2){
    samples[i/2] = (float)getSample(input,i) / (float)Short.MAX_VALUE;
  }
```

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087668/how-to-convert-pcm-samples-in-byte-array-as-floating-point-numbers-in-the-range

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar solution, but IMHO a little cleaner. Unfortunately, there's no good library method as far as I'm aware:  *This assumes the even bytes are the lower bytes

```
private static float[] bytesToFloats(byte[] bytes) {
    float[] floats = new float[bytes.length / 2];
    for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i+=2) {
        floats[i/2] = bytes[i] | (bytes[i+1] << 8);
    }
    return floats;
}
```

Comment: This only works for unsigned PCM, right?  Otherwise you'd need to mask the sign bit from the second in each pair of bytes.

Comment: @hertzsprung : Can you please explain what to do in case of signed PCM ?

Answer (score 3):

You may try using the ByteBuffer API.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asFloatBuffer()

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by hertzsprung the answer by jk. only works for unsigned PCM. On Android PCM16 is big-endian signed, so you need to account for the potentially negative value, encoded in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). This means we need to check whether the high byte is greater than 127 and if so subtract 256 from it first before multiplying it by 256.

```
private static float[] bytesToFloats(byte[] bytes) {
    float[] floats = new float[bytes.length / 2];
    for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i+=2) {
        floats[i/2] = bytes[i] | (bytes[i+1] < 128 ? (bytes[i+1] << 8) : ((bytes[i+1] - 256) << 8));
    }
    return floats;
}
```