# How to trim PCM data to identify sample count or frame count to feed?

Tags: audio, pcm, audio-fingerprinting, downsampling

I want to feed libsamplerate (a library to downsample audio data which needs the following struct filled:

```
typedef struct
  {   float  *data_in, *data_out ;

      long   input_frames, output_frames ;
      long   input_frames_used, output_frames_gen ;

      int    end_of_input ;

      double src_ratio ;
  } SRC_DATA ;
```

The fields of this struct which must be filled in by the caller are:

```
  data_in       : A pointer to the input data samples.
  input_frames  : The number of frames of data pointed to by data_in.
  data_out      : A pointer to the output data samples.
  output_frames : Maximum number of frames pointer to by data_out.
  src_ratio     : Equal to output_sample_rate / input_sample_rate.
  end_of_input  : Equal to 0 if more input data is available and 1 
                  otherwise.
```

To fill this struct, I have data_in but I don't know the frame count so I cannot define input_frames.
Is there an easy way to trim the PCM byte stream? So I can input it into this function also with the correct number of frames.
(So this question is not directly related to libsamplerate)

Comment: I imagine that you you are intended to chunk the audio - say 1024 frames at a time (hence the `end_of_input` member in the struct).  Obviously your final call might have less when you know you're at the end of the stream.

Comment: "I have data_in but I don't know the frame count" You have an array of input samples, but you don't know how many samples you have?

Comment: @BjornRoche ok, I think I can calculate samples by dividing byte size of data_in by 2 (multiply by 8 (bit) and divide by 16(bit) for 44100 16bit mono cpm and for stereo divide all by 2 again..) But I may not be at the beginning of a frame.. So I think I have to discard those bytes before giving them as input. That's why I think I need to find that point to trim the audio. Am I wrong?

Comment: Don't put 16-bit arrays into libsamplerate. data_in and data_out are clearly marked a type float, so you must convert to that type first. I think you need to read up a bit on the basics: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013/05/the-abcs-of-pcm-uncompressed-digital.html